# ODBC vs JDBC vs ADO.NET

Tags: .net, database

What exactly are ODBC, JDBC and ADO.NET? What are the links between them?

Comment: Did you read through the Wikipedia pages for each of them? If so, what specifically is still unclear?

Comment: This one is screaming for LMGTFY. Must resist temptation!

Comment: @JohnFx: Well, more like RT*M (read the <bleep> manual) in a sense.  In another sense, I think its a valid question in that the link between the three may not be clear to a newbie (the second part question per se).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are all different data access technologies.

[ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) is an (older) open standard.  It's designed to be database and technology neutral.  JDBC and ADO.NET can both actually use ODBC internally as a provider, if requested.

[JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc) is a similar concept, but designed to be a standard for Java.

[ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) is a .NET data access technology.

Comment: ADO.Net is much more than just DataSet.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, of course... But, conceptually, it uses a slightly differnet approach, where the DataSet is disconnected from the source.  Guess the idea didn't come across well - just removed it.

Answer (score 15):

ODBC (Open Database Connectivity) is a standard API that can be used to communicate with databases.

JDBC (Java Database Connectivity) is a Java standard that can be used to communicate with databases.

ADO.Net is a .Net standard that can be used to communicate with databases.

Individual databases, such as SQL Server or MySQL, have drivers that implement each of these APIs.

In addition, there are ODBC implementations for JDBC and ADO.Net that allow them to use ODBC drivers.